# to input data from a csv file in cpp

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to input data(numerical values) in a csv file(values seperated by commas), to a cpp file-executable to be run in terminal to see the motion of robot in rviz??Data contains the position of robot joints at different times,part of the csv file contains values like these,each column representing each joint.

1.388106    -0.593356   -1.524699   -1.468721   1.585204    -88.993656  20.192482   -46.047969  -31.037494  12.317457   1.535528    -29.353799  -89.148412  -20.592636  20.303178   22.044684
1.222005    -0.618795   -1.484478   -1.458752   1.548821    -88.940772  20.628733   -46.40773   -30.980427  10.593311   1.577927    -28.24077   -89.131682  -20.840441  21.234292   22.269685
0.912665    -0.666179   -1.409592   -1.440303   1.48104 -88.842338  21.44113    -47.07769   -30.874201  7.402907    1.658714    -26.159671  -89.100513  -21.301901  22.968179   22.688747
0.483921    -0.731897   -1.305772   -1.414634   1.387132    -88.705916  22.56705    -48.006169  -30.72695   3.01525 1.773535    -23.261877  -89.057369  -21.94138   25.371108   23.26944
-0.040279   -0.812168   -1.178862   -1.38335    1.272311    -88.539071  23.943755   -49.141486  -30.546927  -2.300542
-1.279702   -1.002047   -0.878746   -1.309267   1.000844    -88.144647  27.198731   -51.825795  -30.121219  -14.640345  2.279228    -11.180994  -88.879752  -24.572118  35.256071   25.658447
-1.947199   -1.10432    -0.717115   -1.269332   0.854625

following is the publishJoint.cpp file:

```
#include <string>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
ros::init(argc, argv, "publishJoints");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher joint_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("joint_states", 100);
ros::Rate loop_rate(1000000);

const double degree = M_PI/180;

// robot state
double swivel=0;
double tilt=0;


// message declarations
sensor_msgs::JointState joint_state;

joint_state.name.resize(17);
joint_state.position.resize(17);

while (ros::ok()) {
    //update joint_state
    joint_state.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

    swivel=0;
    joint_state.name[0] ="m3joint_mt4_j0";
    joint_state.position[0] = swivel;

    joint_state.name[1] ="m3joint_mt4_j1";
    joint_state.position[1] = tilt;

    joint_state.name[2] ="m3joint_slave_mt4_j2";
    joint_state.position[2] = swivel;

    joint_state.name[3] ="left_shoulder_pan_joint";
    joint_state.position[3] = tilt;

    joint_state.name[4] ="left_shoulder_lift_joint";
    joint_state.position[4] = tilt;

    joint_state.name[5] ="left_elbow_pan_joint";
    joint_state.position[5] = tilt;

    joint_state.name[6] ="left_elbow_lift_joint";
    joint_state.position[6] = tilt;

    joint_state.name[7] ="m3joint_ma14_j4";
    joint_state.position[7] = tilt;

    joint_state.name[8] ="m3joint_ma14_j5";
    joint_state.position[8] = tilt;

    joint_state.name[9] ="m3joint_ma14_j6";
    joint_state.position[9] = tilt;

    joint_state.name[10] ="right_shoulder_pan_joint";
    joint_state.position[10] = swivel;

    joint_state.name[11] ="right_shoulder_lift_joint";
    joint_state.position[11] = swivel;

    joint_state.name[12] ="right_elbow_pan_joint";
    joint_state.position[12] = swivel;

    joint_state.name[13] ="right_elbow_lift_joint";
    joint_state.position[13] = swivel;

    joint_state.name[14] ="m3joint_ma12_j4";
    joint_state.position[14] = swivel;

    joint_state.name[15] ="m3joint_ma12_j5";
    joint_state.position[15] = swivel;

    joint_state.name[16] ="m3joint_ma12_j6" ;
    joint_state.position[16] = swivel;

 tilt += 0.000001;

    //send the joint state and transform
    joint_pub.publish(joint_state);

    // This will adjust as needed per iteration
    loop_rate.sleep();
}

return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10369/to-input-data-from-a-csv-file-in-cpp/) by [ram](https://answers.ros.org/users/641/ram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2011-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First your code is missing something to read the csv and fill the joint_state properly.

When you have done that there are two ways to create the appropriate [transformations](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf):

1. Write a program that receives those joint states you send out and publishes the correct transformations.
2. Create a [URDF](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf) description of your robot and use a robot_state_publisher. The robot_state_publisher takes the robot description and the current joint states and publishes correct transformations from that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ram](https://answers.ros.org/users/641/ram/) on 2011-06-26**:
@dornhege how to go about in c++..(sample program to read a csv file)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-23**:
I don't know about any ROS facilities for reading csv files. You can just use plain c++.

**Comment by [ram](https://answers.ros.org/users/641/ram/) on 2011-06-23**:
@dornhege sorry if i have not been clear, my query starts with how to read the csv file? and i have created the urdf description of the robot and have used robot_state_publisher in my launch file and able to launch it in rviz.

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2015-06-02**:
http://lmgtfy.com/?q=read+csv+file+cpp